# Expect Script to Send Different String Outputs

Tags: unix, terminal, tcl, expect

I have something like this.

```
expect 
 "hi"    { send "You said hi\n" } 
 "hello" { send "Hello yourself\n" } 
 "hi"    { send "2nd time you said hi\n" }
```

The scenario is I will get a initial response 'hi', then 'hello', then 'hi' again. The second time I get a response of 'hi', I want to send a different string.

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect

Answer (score 3):

You should use a list and iterate...

```
set responses {{You said hi} {2nd time you said hi}}
set idx 0
while {$idx < [llength $responses]} {
    expect {
     "hi"    { send [lindex $responses $idx]\n; incr idx } 
     "hello" { send "Hello yourself\n" } 
    }
}
```